# PHP shell_exec from a script doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, shell, ssh

Im using a PHP that needs to run a PHP in the background. Im using shell_exec to do it and passing the parameters it needs to run correctly.

Example:

```
shell_exec('php /home/nobounces/crons/process3.php ' . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ' ' . $job['job_id'] . '  >/dev/null 2>&1');
```

However, when run from a PHP script under the user "nobounces" it doesn't run at all.

I tested the exact same call via SSH as root and it works smoothly.

Am I missing something in the call?

The `">/dev/null 2>&1"` is there to avoid waiting for the response as it could take hours for the script to finish.

Comment: Most likely that account does not have the php executable in its `PATH` environment variable. Try with the absolute path to the php interpreter, probably `/usr/bin/php`.

Comment: what will happen if you just type php  in console?  will it work? if no ,set the path 1st

Comment: Trying to find the path to PHP in a cPanel installation, already tried with /usr/bin/php but it seems its not there cause its still not working.

Comment: Found it: `/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php /home/nobounces/crons/process3.php ' . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ' ' . $job['job_id'] . '  >/dev/null 2>&1` but now the script is awaiting for the output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As running on a cpanel server, the solution was to use:

```
shell_exec('/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php /home/nobounces/crons/process3.php ' . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ' ' . $job['job_id'] . ' >/dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

You can also use PHP-CGI using the path:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php-cgi
```

Thanks @arkascha for your suggestion.